# How to know if $p$ is spanned by the set $\lbrace p1,p2,p3\rbrace$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know how to solve the question if you have a set of polynomials

$$
p_1 = 1 + x,
$$
$$
p_2 = 1 + 2x + x^2,
$$
$$
p_3 = 1 + 3x + 3x^2 + x^3,
$$
and if the polynomial $p = 2017 + x^2 + 26x^3$ is spanned by the set 
$S = \{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$

Thank you

Comment: What does it mean for a polynomial to span a set?  If you are somehow talking about vector spaces....well, $S$ looks three dimensional so how could one vector span it?

Comment: Is it possible that you mean to ask:  is $p(x)$ in the linear span of $\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$  (maybe over $\mathbb R$....who knows?).?  If so, then you have a system of linear equations.  Write $p(x)=Ap_1+Bp_2+Cp_3$ and note that $A+B+C=2017$ and so on.  Helps to remark that $C=26$.

Comment: You should add more information like which is the field (if is a vector space) or the ring (if is a module)?

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Yes it is a vector space

Answer (score 0):

If the polynomials are over $\mathbb{R}$, the question is solved by a linear system given by:

As $1,x,x^2,x^3$ are l.i. then the eaquation $p=ap_1+bp_2+cp_3$ is solved by$$\begin{cases} a+b+c=2017\\a+2b+3c=0\\b+3c=1\\c=26\end{cases}$$

So as the system don't have a solution the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x+1=t$

Then $p=26(t-1)^3 +(t-1)^2 +2017=26t^3-77t^2+76t+1992$

Since there exists a constant, $p$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of
$t, t^2, t^3$